# What if my PDF is proportional to some known PDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If I had some probability density function (of a random variable X) which is proportional to the density of a "known" distribution e.g Gamma or Gaussian. Is it enough to deduce that X has that "known" distribution? I would appreciate some explanation behind this! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange!

Answer (score 6):

Let us suppose that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continous real valued pdfs such that $f_1 \propto f_2$, ie there exists $\alpha$ such that $f_1(x) = \alpha f_2(x)$ for all $x$.

Then $1 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_1 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \alpha f_2 = \alpha \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_2 = \alpha$. So $\alpha =1$ and we conclude that $f_1 = f_2$

Comment: Why is this valid? Suppose we know that f1 = 5f2 then by the argument above we show 1=5 which is false?

Comment: Their argument shows a PDF cannot be proportional to another PDF unless it is trivial: $\alpha =1$. Your example demonstrates this via contradiction.

Comment: @JDoe - the point is that a PDF must have one property: the area under the curve must be exactly $1$.  So it is impossible to have $f_1 = 5 f_2$ since one area would be $5$ times bigger than the other area.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide an argument inspired by yet slightly different to [Jsevillamol](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/240304/jsevillamol)'s answer. Suppose you have a pdf $q=Cf$, with $C$ as a normalization constant. You find that the essential part $f$ of $q$ is proportional to some known pdf $p$, i.e., $f=C'p$. Then,
$$
\int q = \int Cf = \int CC'p = CC'\int p=1.
$$
Hence, $CC'=1$, and $q=Cf=CC'p=p$. This concludes that the pdf $q$ at your hand is exactly some known pdf $p$.